# send php array data to jquery

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have been trying to send data store in an array to query.

this is in a loop (php)

```
<?php 
    $arraydata[] = array('qty'=>$item->quantity, 'id' => $item->item_id); 
?>
```

trying to pass the data to arraydata attr.

```
<button 
    class="btn btn-success approve-order" 
    data-arraydata="<?php echo json_encode($arraydata); ?>" >Approve Order
   </button>
```

this is my javascript code

```
$(function () {
 $(document).on('click','.approve-order',function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     let dataarray = $(this).data('arraydata');
     console.log(dataarray);
   });
});
```

Comment: You need to let us know what your issue is. _"I've been trying to"_ isn't much of an explanation. Don't let us guess what the issue might be.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.parseJSON` to parse json string to javascript array,

```
$(function () {
 $(document).on('click','.approve-order',function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     let dataarray = $(this).data('arraydata');
     console.log($.parseJSON(dataarray));
   });
});
```

Comment: Humble request to all respected users that allow new users to explain a question clearly so that will make website clean.

Comment: @TarangP true, but OP is looks like he dint parse his json string to javascript array

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried use the $.parseJSON(dataarray), but I am getting this "Unexpected end of JSON input". All I want to do is to send php array to JavaScript.

Comment: @A.Emmanuel - You should look at the generated HTML. Most likely, the issue is that when you json encode the array a, it will contain `"`, which will break your HTML attribute (since it's wrapped with `"`).